# Why is my rocker/shiny container is 2 GB?

Tags: r, docker, shiny

```
# Base image https://hub.docker.com/u/rocker/
FROM rocker/shiny:latest

# system libraries of general use
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    libmysqlclient-dev
    
# remove example apps
RUN sudo rm -r  /srv/shiny-server/*

# copy index page
COPY /index.html /srv/shiny-server/index.html

# copy shiny-server.conf
COPY /shiny-server.conf /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf

# copy  apps
COPY /app1 /srv/shiny-server/app1
COPY /app2 /srv/shiny-server/app2

#copy renv
COPY /renv/profiles/prod/renv.lock ./renv.lock

# install renv & restore packages
RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("renv");renv::consent(provided = TRUE);renv::restore()'

#copy run.sh that contains multiple commands
COPY ./run.sh ./run.sh

RUN chmod +x /run.sh


CMD ["./run.sh"]
```

This is the `Dockerfile` that i am using in order to dockerize my shiny apps. The base image is 456 MB but the final container the build is 2 GB. The files that i copy are 3 MB each and I dont think R libraries installed after `renv::restore()` are 1.5 GB. Then why is my image is so big and how can i optimize it?

Comment: If you do `docker history <image name>` you should be able to see each layer and how much space that layer adds to the image.

Comment: Also check the [r-minimal](https://github.com/r-hub/r-minimal) images which are based on Alpine Linux instead of Ubuntu.

Comment: @HansKilian I ran ```docker history <image name>``` and apparently ```RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("renv");renv::consent(provided = TRUE);renv::restore()'```takes up 522MB of space! Also, there is a layer that is not included in the dockerfile ```RUN /bin/sh -c /rocker_scripts/install_R.sh  ...``` which takes up 779 MB of space. Could latter originated from base image?

Comment: You should be able to see the size of the base `rocker/shiny` image in your registry. On the image page on Docker hub, it says that it's 456MB: https://hub.docker.com/layers/rocker/shiny/latest/images/sha256-270cdc63dcc7acb985fe5fe7aa00361d006339270abdda0a4ea45c821af311cd?context=explore